# Creating envelope lock in docusign using 'edit' lockType not working

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am trying to create an **envelope lock** in `nodejs` using [docusign-esign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusign-esign) **npm package** from [this](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes) example.

**Here is the code**:

```
let token = 'thisismytoken';
let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
dsApiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient), results = null;

let envelope = module.exports.makeEnvelopeFromTemplate2(data);

results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(
                  data.account_id,
                  {envelopeDefinition: envelope}
          );
let envelopeId = results.envelopeId;

let lockRequest = new docusign.LockRequest.constructFromObject({
      lockedByApp : 'My APP',
      lockDurationInSeconds : '300',
      lockType : 'edit' 
});

envelopesApi.createLock(data.account_id, 
      envelopeId, 
      lockRequest
);
```

But I am getting this error.

```
{ 
   "errorCode" : "EDIT_LOCK_INVALID_LOCK_TYPE","message":"Invalid lock type."
}
```

Comment: Can you try capturing an API log of the failing lock request call? There may be an issue with how the DocuSign package is interpreting your lock definition. Adding the raw json of the call request to your question would show if there's a difference between what you're defining and what is getting sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Drew. I was following the example from [this](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes) website. But i changed the code from `docusign.lockRequest.constructFromObject` to `docusign.LockRequest.constructFromObject` because the first one gives me "Cannot read property 'constructFromObject' of undefined" error. I am not sure if this is what causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to trace the issue and created an envelope lock successfully. I updated to code from this

```
envelopesApi.createLock(
      data.account_id, 
      envelopeId, 
      lockRequest
);
```

to this

```
await envelopesApi.createLock(
           data.account_id, 
           envelopeId, 
           {
                lockRequest: lockRequest
           }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul, thanks. I think you found a tiny bug in the blog post, which I'll fix.
However, your issue is strange, because the lock type is valid.
I suspect the error message is wrong.
I wonder if the issue is a result of you creating an envelope and immediately trying to lock it. Maybe some race weird bug.
Can you try to set an envelopeID from a well established envelope that existed for more than 5 minutes in the system and lock it? I think that may be the reason. Maybe you need to put some delay between the two activities.

Comment: Hi @Inbar, thank you for your blog post. I updated my code and I was able to create an envelop lock.

Comment: Did you test your blog post? Some of the codes are not working.

Comment: which code do you refer to? there was a typo which I fixed after I saw this question. That was in the node.JS code. Do you have any other issues with the code in the blog post?

Comment: Hi @Inbar. In Node,js code, I tried this part

 `let apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient(basePath);
  let config = new docusign.Configuration(apiClient);
  config.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(config);` 

and I'm getting this error

`TypeError: config.addDefaultHeader is not a function`

Not sure if this is from my end or not, but if you tested it, then its from my end.

Comment: very sorry, this was a copy/paste error. It should be:



let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
dsApiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient)